# Possible to change the TypeScript interface for built in JavaScript object (JSON)?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, types, interface

JSON.strigify() breaks with cyclic objects (as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value )

The same article recommends 'cycle.js' - which adds 2 methods to the global JSON object - .decycle() & .retrocycle() to stringify cyclic objects.

This works great, but typescript complains unless I add

//@ts-ignore

or other ts hacks - JSON [ 'retrocycle' ] (), etc - which I can do but it's not pretty.

Is there anyway to create something like a "JSON.d.ts" file to override the default TS interface for the global JSON object?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this was closed & then re-opened - but by putting together several threads, I came up with this - in case anyone else is interested:

Create a .d.ts typefile, say in src/custom_types:

**src/custom_types/JSON.d.ts**

In JSON.d.ts:

```
export declare global {
    interface JSON {
            decycle(object: any, replacer?: any): string;
            retrocycle(something: any): any;
    }
}
```

In tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    ...
    "paths" : {
      ...
    "*" : ["src/custom_types/*"],
    }
  },
  "typeRoots": [
    ....
    "src/custom_types/",
    ],
}
```